# Evaluating algorithms from 'untrusted' users

Tags: python, security, web-applications, eval

I was just toying around with an idea, and I couldn't think of a way to resolve this in the backend without daunting security issues.

Say I want to give users the opportunity to create simple algorithms via a webservice and test these over small lists, e.g. `range(0, 5)` then report back the results back via another webservice, a template, or an email, doesn't really matter, it's the evaluation that bothers me.

Using python:

```
class Algorithm(whatever):
    function = whatever.CharField(max_length=75)
```

A user might enter something like:

```
'f(x)=x+(x/5)**0.75'
```

Of course I could use `eval`, stripping any built-ins, strings other than "x" etc., but this would still likely be unfortunate practice.

The only thing I could come up with is to *move any evaluation functionality to a JavaScript front end.*

Comment: Well, Google certainly does this sort of thing in their codejams. So I wonder how they solve this issue. Perhaps run untrusted code a VM with the required setup. So even if they bork the VM, you're still safe

Comment: if you remove eventual "import" key word nothing should happen in terms of data damage.

Comment: @MaxLi What about `__import__`?

Comment: @kuyan while "import" in UserInput: UserInput=UserInput.replace("import","") - I meant something like this under "import" removal

Comment: [There are already several questions on the same subject.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bpython%5d%20safe%20eval) I would recommend moving evaluation to JavaScript.

Comment: Services used for online contests usually runs such user-delivered code in some kind of sandbox. E.g. in a separate process with restricted permissions and/or watched by supervisor process. But it may be the overkill in your case. You may read something about sandboxing in Python 
[here](http://tinyurl.com/c9vulou).

Using regexp seems risky to me, since it is almost certain, that you will miss something.

Also, you can write a simple parser/checker for a chosen subset of Python. I am not joking - it's not very hard, but also not completely trivial. But again - it may be an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval()` is evil,  and doing this on the backend is very dangerous.  However it could be done safely using a [python sandbox](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython).  But if the sandbox where to fail,  you would get owned.  Which is not a very "defense in depth" approach.

A better approach would be to evaluate the payload on the client side...  However this is Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).  One way to prevent an attacker from being able to exploit this issue,  is have an event handler on the client side that evaluates the form when a button is pressed.  If the attacker can build a GET or POST request that executes JavaScript then he can exploit the XSS vulnerability.   Also make sure to set `x-frame-options:  deny` to prevent [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).